# File Transfer via Internet ( using java)

Tags: java, image, networking, udp, video-streaming

I've a java(swing) application running on server and client(or assume two different

computers),These two are connected through Internet not by LAN or WAN..The client has to send

some data (around 200 kb) to the server.Which method is preferable for transferring data..I used

TCP through LAN,but it's working slow through Internet..So can I use UDP for internet ?  If yes, I don't

know how to divide my data into chunks and send it & again re-assemble the data at the server.

I am really thankful if source code is provided for UDP transfer(bulk data in java).

thanks in advance..

Comment: 1.) stay with TCP, make sure you use Buffered Readers/Streams/Writers. 2:) learn how the formatting works in Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 4):

**Use TCP**, it does exactly what you want in a way which is much better than you can hope to implement on your own. If you have low bandwidth, transfer in the background or just wait - there is nothing you can do with that.

Read your data in byte arrays and write them as a whole - see DataInputStream.readFully(). Flush the output at the end of the writing.

**Edit:**If you want to send multiple images, one after the other, you can do video compression - it is designed to be efficient just at that.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.Here the client has to capture its screenshots(awt.Robot) continously (say for each second) and send each image to server(with a time  delay of 1 sec)..but the screenshots are coming very slow to the server..By the way how can I grab only the changed parts of an image and patch it to the previous image which is almost similar but with a little change.

Comment: Well you can always compress the images more, using for example JPEG compression? If not, you basically need higher bandwidth..

Comment: user702076 - you are keeping asking that question? Didn't I tell you to look at the pixels? What if you have 2 images, each 2x2 pixels, the first one is (123, 123, 124, 125) then second (123, 123, 123, 123) - guess which pixels have changed in the second?

Comment: Ravi, you are kidding us, posting the same question multiple times is counterproductive. You should rather post ONCE and describe your problem in detail and investigate the answers you get seriously.

Comment: @Ravi - have you checked that the bottleneck is not Robot? I used it a long time ago and it was very slow in creating screen shots.

Comment: @Ravi it is possible to update your question with more details or clarifications - for example like in this response :)

Answer (score 1):

Ravi is struggeling for some days now with this problem. Now UDP is expected to bring help, but, of course, it won't!

Ravi, I give you some more hints for free (as you have not upvoted even one of the 7 answers you have received until now, I guess the reputation system in StackOverflow is and remains a mystery to you):

1. Computer 2D-images are nothing more
   than a 2 dimensional array of pixels, i.e. color
   values (usually int values).
2. The BufferedImage class has methods to get and set each pixel individually, I told you yesterday.
3. Two equal sized Images are different, if there is a coordinate x,y where the corresponding pixel in one image is not the same as in the other image.

BTW, may I ask what your profession is?

Comment: Mr.Ingo I am java programmer just completed my graduation 6 months back.Now I work for Zinniaas Technologies(India)..I mostly work on Web Applications ( involves JSF,HIBERNATE,SPRING)..I know a very little on Java Networking..That's Y I am Struggling ??? I think u understood my pain..Mybad If I bothered u so much....

Comment: Your problem has nothing to do with Networking. You already have a network connection, it works just like any other file.

Comment: Let me try and help a little more. A stream of screenshots (1/second) is like a low framerate movie (1 frame / sec). You can use video compression techniques, and decompress at the other end immediately, or just record the video stream and decompress it later when required.